# Mongolite - distinct too big, 16mb cap

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I'm trying to query my database `ratingsChoices= m$distinct({'answers'})` but I get a `Warning: Error in : distinct too big, 16mb cap`

Is there a way around this error in `mongolite`? I've seen some similar problems with PyMongo, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way around this error in mongolite?

The problem here is because [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/#dbcmd.distinct) command is called when you're calling `m$distinct`. See more [MongoDB Database commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) for more information.

The `distinct` command returns a single document. The [maximum BSON document size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/) limit is 16 MegaBytes. So, if you have either lots of distinct values and/or large fields that would exceed the maximum size of 16MB returned by the server, you'll get the above error message.

An alternative, is to utilise [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) instead of the `distinct` command. Which fortunately `mongolite` has support for: [mongolite aggregate](https://jeroen.github.io/mongolite/calculation.html#aggregate).

Aggregation pipeline results are returned via a cursor, which can be iterated upon. This means you can fetch results more than the 16MB maximum limit.

For example (using MongoDB v3.6 and mongolite v2017-12-21):

```
uniqueName <- m$aggregate('[{"$group":{"_id":"$answers"}}]')
print(uniqueName)
```